# Android Application works fine on emulator but force close on phone?

Tags: android

I have an application which lists our current location, speed etc on textviews. This application works fine on emulator. Then I copied the apk file to phone using data cable. Phone was on usb mode. Then I installed the file. But when I run t, I got a force close. Why is that? please help.

Comment: can you post the device logs?

Comment: if you don't post your code and your logcat stacktrace we can't help you

Comment: It's hard to tell without any info, but I would suggest checking you have added required permissions to your manifest file.

Comment: The permissions given are    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: I have also used intents to show map of the current location and video in youtube corresponding to the address. They are selected from menu.

Answer (score 1):

you might not have working internet connection

Check your internet connection and see if your GPS is working or not

if not then put error catching try-catch block to avoid FORCE CLOSE

Comment: I was able to use maps and to connect to Android market. So GPS and Internet should be okay, I think. But it took a while to get the current location. It showed unable to get current location many times when I used one inbuilt app. in phone. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Map----- public void showMap()
    {
     /*Intent intent = new Intent(TravelGuide.this, MapOption.class);
        startActivity(intent);*/
     Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
     Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:" + Double.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + "," + Double.valueOf(location.getLongitude()) + "?z=15" ) );
        startActivity(intent);
     
     
    }

Comment: video------public void showVideo(){
     /*Intent i = new Intent(TravelGuide.this, VideoSearch.class);
        startActivity(i);*/
     if(addresses != null) {
     String videoId = strReturnedAddress.toString();
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+videoId+"+tourism&aq=f")); 
     //intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId); 
     startActivity(intent); 
     }
     else{
      Toast.makeText(this, "Can not get video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    }

Comment: The address variable is given to search video and geo coordinates  to map

Comment: When I open an inbuilt map app., It shows waiting for location for long long time. Is that the problem?

Comment: It works fine now. In a website, I saw that it can be because the GPS is not warmed up enough to get the location info. I played with the inbuilt map applications for a while and then opened my app. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not enabled my location in settings of your phone... Enable that in settings and try again !

Comment: My location is set on my phone